# Javascript to parse GET parameter from string - what is throwing this off?

Tags: javascript, query-string

I have been using the following function to get regular parameters from the current url:

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURI(
        (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
    );
}
```

However, I want to get the GET parameter 'imgurl' from a string that will follow the format for the url [here](http://www.google.com/imgres?um=1&hl=en&safe=off&client=ubuntu&sa=N&tbo=d&channel=fs&biw=1854&bih=962&tbm=isch&tbnid=Lfj0vtCQt7S_YM%3a&imgrefurl=http://beautiful-pics.org/wayne-rooney/&docid=ZFU0V885e5LlqM&imgurl=http://beautiful-pics.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Wayne_Rooney_4.jpg&w=415&h=512&ei=783TULHIA6Wp2gX154HgBQ&zoom=1).

When I change that function to handle regular strings:

```
function getURLParameter(name, givenstring) {
    return decodeURI(
        (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(givenstring.search)||[,null])[1]
    );
}
```

It returns null. I even made a userscript go to the url that I just gave you and I used the first function to try to get that 'imgurl' parameter, but it was unable to do so. I also got rid of the colons in that url, but obviously that did nothing.

What is throwing this function off about this string format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`location.search` is the query-string part of the current URL. If you want to replace that with an arbitrary string variable `givenstring`, then you would replace `location.search` with `givenstring`, *not* with `givenstring.search`. So:

```
function getURLParameter(name, givenstring) {
    return decodeURI(
        (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(givenstring)||[,null])[1]
    );
}
```

By the way, your function will misbehave if (for example) the string is `foobar=baz&bar=bip` and the parameter of interest is `bar`. It will find the first instance of `bar=...`, which in this case is `bar=baz` rather than `bar=bip`. You can fix that by using `(^|&)`:

```
function getURLParameter(name, givenstring) {
    return decodeURI(
        (RegExp('(^|&)' + name + '=(.+?)(&|$)').exec(givenstring)||[,,null])[2]
    );
}
```

(Your function will also misbehave if `name` has any special characters in it — either special in URLs or special in regexes — but I'm guessing that you have enough control over `name` that you can make certain that's not going to be an issue?)

Comment: Works great! I don't have much experience with Javascript regex so I just thought .search had something to do with executing regex.

Comment: @MarkLyons: That makes sense. There *is* a regex-related `.search` -- it's a property of strings, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search -- but as it happens, that's not what `location.search` refers to, because `location` is not a string.